# Prolog: How do I remove symmetrical values in predicates

Tags: database, duplicates, prolog

I have a question regarding the removal of symmetrical values in
my predicates. These predicates are in my database and I used
assertz to add them there.

So I have:

```
foo(a,b).
foo(b,a).
foo(c,d).
foo(e,f).
foo(f,e).
```

I'm trying to remove

```
foo(b,a).
foo(f,e).
```

An I tried to make this rule:

```
remove :- foo(A,B),foo(B,A),retract(foo(B,A)).
```

However, this removes all the predicates in my DB and I don't know how
to prevent that.

If someone could help me I'd really appreciate it!

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two distinct semantics for [retract/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=retract/1):

- **immediate update view**: upon backtracking, retracted clauses can no longer be seen (they became invisible immediately).
- **logical update view**: upon backtracking, retracted clauses can still be seen (they became invisible only on the next predicate call). This update view is the ISO standard.

In the logical update view, for example, when the predicate `remove/1` is called:

- First it sees `foo(a,b)` and `foo(b,a)` and hence it retracts `foo(b,a)`.
- Afterward, upon backtracking, it sees `foo(b,a)` and `foo(a,b)` and hence it also retracts `foo(a,b)`.

To solve the problem, you can use the ISO built-in predicate [once/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=once/1) (which prevents backtracking).

```
:- dynamic foo/2.

foo(a,b).
foo(b,a). 
foo(c,d).
foo(e,f).
foo(f,e).

remove :- 
    once( ( foo(A, B),
            foo(B, A),
            retract(foo(B, A)) ) ).
```

To **retract only one symmetrical fact**, you can ask:

```
?- listing(foo), remove, listing(foo).
:- dynamic foo/2.

foo(a, b).
foo(b, a). % <== only this fact is retracted!
foo(c, d).
foo(e, f).
foo(f, e).

:- dynamic foo/2.

foo(a, b).
foo(c, d).
foo(e, f).
foo(f, e).

true.
```

To **retract all symmetrical facts**, you can define:

```
remove_all_sym :-
    (   remove
    ->  remove_all_sym
    ;   true ).
```

Example:

```
?- listing(foo), remove_all_sym, listing(foo).
:- dynamic foo/2.

foo(a, b).
foo(b, a). % <== this fact is retracted!
foo(c, d).
foo(e, f).
foo(f, e). % <== this fact is retracted!

:- dynamic foo/2.

foo(a, b).
foo(c, d).
foo(e, f).
```

**NOTE** A better alternative would be to avoid inserting symmetrical facts into the database:

```
assert_foo(A, B) :-
    (   foo(B, A)          
    ->  true                
    ;   assertz(foo(A, B)) ).
```

Comment: you're a lifesaver thank you so much it finally worked!

Comment: If one is using SWI-Prolog then the better way is to use [assertz/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=assertz/2) and [erase/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=erase/1)

Comment: @GuyCoder To use `erase/1` in SWI-Prolog, you must have the reference to the clause to be removed from the database, but this reference is not known at the time the clause is removed by the predicate `remove/0`. How could OP be resolved with `erase/1`? Could you elaborate a more detailed answer?

Comment: @slago With SWI-Prolog for a stored database I use [library(persistency)](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=persistency).

Comment: @GuyCoder Nice! But I think that using library(persistence) is not the case in the OP. Anyway, that's a good advice for OP.

Comment: Your answer is very useful however the question was in a very specific context. As we know others will try and take an answer and apply it to a more general situation and fail miserably. Thus the comment. But as you noted my comment is not an exact fit for the question. The real problem is that many don't cross the divide for Prolog and learn how to really use it correctly or to make use of all of it's benefits. :-(

Comment: @GuyCoder It is true! As I said, I agree with you that this would be the best solution in a more general situation (clearly, if **SWI-Prolog** is being used).

Comment: A better alternative would be to **not** call this assert, and to refine the test when asserting can be avoided. Here is a counterexample: `foo(a,b)` is in the database, and now I want to add `foo(a,_)`.

Comment: With SWI-Prolog if one has the head then one can get the reference with [clause/3](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=clause/3), e.g. `?- clause(foo(a,b),_,Ref).
Ref = <clause>(0000000006C00210).` `?- clause(foo(b,a),_,Ref).
Ref = <clause>(0000000006C01710).` Note that the reference is a [blob](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/blob-types/4364) and doesn't always play nice; in other words don't expect a blob to work in the same place as a term.

Comment: @GuyCoder That's true, but this does not solve the problem with the logical update view. For example, upon backtracking, the query  `?- assertz(foo(a,b)), assertz(foo(b,a)), clause(foo(A,B),_,R1), clause(foo(B,A),_,R2), erase(R2).`  still retract both facts `foo(a,b)` and `foo(b.a)`.

Comment: @false Are you suggesting that the better alternative would be to exclude the predicates `assertz/1` and `rectract/1` from the ISO standard? If not, could you present a better alternative solution for the OP?

Comment: @slago: I commented `assert_foo/2` only.

Comment: @false `assert_foo/2` is aiming to assert a ground fact for predicate `foo/2`. The term `foo(a,_)` is not a ground fact.

Comment: @slago: You do not state this anywhere.

Comment: @false Yes, because it's implicit in OP description.  Anyway, if this is not enough clear in my answer, the OP can ask me.

Comment: thank you to all but since I'm a beginner I'll do what slago did. Thanks to everyone!